# How to access knockoutJS viewmodel from out side

Tags: knockout.js

I was trying to access KnockoutJS `viewmodel` from out side this way. My objective is to push data to KnockoutJS viewmodel from out side.

```
function AddNewData()
{
    //alert("add");
    appViewModel.Stocks.push.apply(self.Stocks,NewData);

    ko.utils.arrayForEach(NewData, function(item)
    {
        //appViewModel.Stocks.push.apply(item);
        alert(item.Name);
        //appViewModel.Stocks.push(ko.mapping.fromJS(item));

    })    

}
```

Here is my JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tridip/62Ls6x9n/161/ which is doing nothing when clicking on add new data.

What is the mistake in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the mistakes:

1. You have two `UpdateData`'s. One is an array and the other is a function.
2. You didn't instantiate `appViewModel`, you just passed a function to `ko.applyBindings`.
3. Your functions are neither members nor prototype methods of the `appViewModel`, so Knockout cannot access them in the HTML view (through click binding in this case). This is only an issue if you want to bind your events in Knockout though.

Nr.2 is why you can't access it; you should first instantiate your viewModel and put it in a variable, like this:

```
var appInstance = new appViewModel(data);
ko.applyBindings(appInstance);
```

Then you can reference your viewmodel through `appInstance[property]`. You can also get the data for a DOM element by doing `ko.dataFor/ ko.contextFor(element)` in your functions.

Fiddle with regular click bindings: http://jsfiddle.net/kevinvanlierde/62Ls6x9n/166/
Fiddle with functions outside your VM: http://jsfiddle.net/kevinvanlierde/62Ls6x9n/170/

Comment: thanks a lot for this help. i understand what i need to do. why we need to pass data this way `AddNewData(NewData)` here NewData will be null. we can call like this way and it will work `AddNewData()`. so what is your suggestion. thanks

Comment: @Thomas True, when your variables are known there's no problem. However 'parameterizing' your function provides more flexibility to pass any data later on, so it's good practice in general